# Copy Constructor Assertion Error

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, copy-constructor, assertion

My copy constructor is failing due to an assertion error. It is saying that the size of the queue is incorrect and I'm not sure why. Here is the code for my Queue class:

```
public class Queue<T> implements UnboundedQueueInterface<T> {

    public Node<T> head;
    public Node<T> tail;
    public int size = 0;

    public Queue() {        
            // TODO 1

    }

    public Queue(Queue<T> other) {
            // TODO 2 
        if(other.head==null){
            this.head=null;}
        else{
        Node<T> newN = new Node<T>(other.head.data);
        newN = other.head;
        while(newN!=null){
            T element = newN.data;
            this.enqueue(element);
            newN = newN.next;}
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
            // TODO 3
      return head==null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
            // TODO 4
            int sum = 0;
            while(head!=null){
                sum+=1;
                head = head.next;
            }
            return sum;

    }

    @Override
    public void enqueue(T element) {
            // TODO 5
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element, null);
        if (isEmpty()) {head = newNode;} else {tail.next = newNode;}
        tail = newNode;
        this.size++;

    }

    @Override
    public T dequeue() throws NoSuchElementException {
            // TODO 6
            if(isEmpty()){ 
                throw new NoSuchElementException("empty queue");}
            else{
                T element = head.data;
                if (tail == head) {
                    tail = null;
                }
                head = head.next;
                this.size--;
                return element;}

    }

    @Override
    public T peek() throws NoSuchElementException {
            // TODO 7
           if(isEmpty()) throw new NoSuchElementException("empty queue");
           else
               return head.data;
    }


    @Override
    public UnboundedQueueInterface<T> reversed() {
            // TODO 8

            Queue<T> output = new Queue<T>(this);
            Node<T> node1 = new Node<T>(output.head.data);
            node1 = output.head;
            Node<T> node2 = new Node<T>(null);  //nextNode
            Node<T> node3 = new Node<T>(null);  //prevNode

            while(node1!=null){
                node2 = node1.next;
                node1.next = node3;
                node3 = node1;
                node1 = node2;
            }
            output.head = node3;
            return output;

            }



}

class Node<T> {
    public T data;
    public Node<T> next;
    public Node(T data) { this.data=data;}
    public Node(T data, Node<T> next) {
        this.data = data; this.next=next;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the test:

```
public void testCopyConstructorEmptyNotAliased() throws Exception  {
        Queue<Integer> q = new Queue<Integer>();
        UnboundedQueueInterface<Integer> r;
        r = new Queue<Integer>(q);
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
        assertTrue(q.isEmpty());        

        q.enqueue(1);
        q.enqueue(2);
        assertEquals(2, q.size());
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());

        r.enqueue(3);
        r.enqueue(4);
        r.enqueue(5);
        assertEquals(2, q.size());
        assertEquals(3, r.size());

        r.dequeue();
        r.dequeue();
        r.dequeue();
        assertTrue(r.isEmpty());
        assertEquals(2, q.size());

        q.dequeue();
        q.dequeue();
        assertTrue(q.isEmpty());
    }
```

Comment: at which line does the AssertionError occurr and which length does the queue have(it will say it in the failure message)

Comment: ah okay I know where the error is coming from. your `public int size()` method actually modifies the member `head` and so after you check the size again the head is on the element after the last one(i.e. null) and the length is 0. you have to create a temporary variable inside your size function

Comment: Thank you! I forgot to even think about that!

Answer (score 0):

You don't even require it to iterate the whole queue to find the size of the queue. As you're already updating the queue size when any enqueue or dequeue operations are performed. You can simply return the size.

```java
 @Override
    public int size() {
            // TODO 4
        return this.size;
    }
```